# Using an Environment Variable in a .NET Core Console App Hosted in Docker

Tags: docker

I have a .NET Core Console App. This console app loads a connection string stored in an environment variable. I'm retrieving that connection string using this code:

```
var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("connection_string");
```

The line above works if I run the Console App by just pushing "play" in Visual Studio. However, if I run this Console App in a Docker container, the `connectionString` is empty. I assume it's because the `connection_string` environment variable is not in the Docker environment. However, I can't figure out how to add/set an environment variable in a Docker container.

For my last attempt, I added the following in my Dockerfile:

```
ENV connection_string <my_connection_string_value>
```

However, that didn't seem to matter. What am I missing?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using an app settings file for that?

Comment: Yes. I don't want the connection string floating around in source control, dev machines, etc. That's why I want to pull from an Environment variable.

Comment: Ok if you get it working I'll check it out, if not encrypt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to easily reference environment variables via the configuration builder.

```html
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
  //...
  .AddEnvironmentVariables()
  .Build();
```

The reference use IConfiguration via DI.

```html
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

public ClassConstructor(IConfiguration configuration)
{
_configuration = configuration ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));

var connectionString = _configuration.GetValue("connection_string");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer assumes a ASP.NET Core environment using the configuration environment. In a pure console app, however, it's fine to just use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`.

This seems not to read the environment variables defined in either *Dockerfile* or provided as parameter *-e*.

The variables defined that way are handed over in the current process. And this is not the default behavior. Hence, the following access will work:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VAR_NAME", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)
```

The key is the second parameter `EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process`.